# Motion of an object near a force field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, kinematics

I'm trying to simulate the motion of an object near a force field, given an initial velocity $v_0$.

I couldn't find anything that fits what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a point of mass $m_1$ in the origin of the Cartesian plane **(0.0, 0.0)** (blue in the image).

The coordinate system is the Cartesian one.

The position of $M_1$ shouldn't change.

I figured out this:

- The attraction force between the blue body and the red body is F defined like this: $F =G{m_0m_1}/{r^2}$ by Newton's theory.
- The resulting position of the red body should be the sum of $v_0$ and a vector representing the component of the motion directed towards the center.

But I didn't get further than that. How could I calculate the position of the body at time t?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying assume the position of $M_1$ is fixed?

Comment: try to pick one coordinate system: either Cartesian $(x, y)$ or Radial $(r,\theta)$. Plot your FBD and write all motion equations in terms of just one coordinate system. you will get your answer.

Comment: @bob d yes sorry I've fixed the question

Comment: @Vikash Kumar what do you mean with fbd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to predict the location of a planet at a given time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228223/how-to-predict-the-location-of-a-planet-at-a-given-time)

Comment: @Fabrizio Free Body Diagram

Answer (score 0):

For the body with mass $m_0$, split the velocity and acceleration vectors into its perpendicular components. Let the body be at position $(a,b)$ initially. The displacement due to the initial velocity will be $s=vt$. Do the same  for the acceleration using the formula $s=\frac 12at^2$. Add them together for the x-components and y-components and you arrive at your answer.